# Debugging my failed code

Tags: java

I'm trying to debug my program for errors; for example when I try to run my code it prints out only the DNA string instead of printing out the gene sequences. The problem area is around the while statement of the printAll method. I need to call the findStopIndex method inside the while loop. But I'm wondering why when I run it I come up empty. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class FindMultiGenes4 {
public
int
 findStopIndex(String dna, int index){
     int stop1 = dna.indexOf("tga", index);
     if (stop1 == -1 || (stop1-index) % 3 != 0){
         stop1 = dna.length();
        }
        int stop2 = dna.indexOf("taa", index);
        if (stop2 == -1 || (stop2-index) % 3 != 0){
            stop2 = dna.length();
        }
        int stop3 = dna.indexOf("tag", index);
        if (stop3 == -1 || (stop3-index) % 3 != 0){
            stop3 = dna.length();
        }
        return Math.min(stop1, Math.min(stop2,stop3));
}
    public void printAll(String dna) {

    dna = "CATGTAATAGATGAATGACTGATAGATATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGACCCA";
    String sequence = dna.toLowerCase();
    int index = 0;
    int newIndex = 0;



    while (true) {
        index = sequence.indexOf("atg", index);
        if (index == -1)
            break;
        if (newIndex == -1) // Check needed only if a stop codon is not guaranteed for each start codon.
            break;
        int stop = findStopIndex(dna, index);
        if (stop != sequence.length()){
            System.out.println("From " + (index  ) + " to " + newIndex+3 + " Gene: " + sequence.substring(index, stop+3));
            index = sequence.substring(index, stop + 3).length();
        }
        else {index = index+3;
        }





    }
}
public void testFinder(){


        FindMultiGenes4 FMG = new FindMultiGenes4();

        String dna = "CATGTAATAGATGAATGACTGATAGATATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGACCCA";

        FMG.printAll(dna);




            System.out.println("DNA: "+dna);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was at the line below

```
int stop = findStopIndex(dna, index);
```

`dna` is upper case string, where as `findStopIndex` checks for lower case gene sequences `tga, taa, tag`.

There are some other minor issues with the code, which I hopefully have corrected, see the modified code below

```
public class FindMultiGenes4 {
    private static final String GENE_PREFIX = "ATG";
    private static final String[] GENE_SUFFIXES = {"TGA", "TAA", "TAG"};

    public int findStopIndex(String dna, int index) {
        int minStop = dna.length();
        for(String suffix : GENE_SUFFIXES) {
            int stop = -1;
            int localIndex = index;
            do{//repeating if the match found is not multiple of 3
                stop = dna.indexOf(suffix, localIndex);
                if(stop == -1) {
                    stop = dna.length();
                    break;
                }
                localIndex = stop + 3;
            } while( (stop - index) % 3 != 0);

            if(minStop > stop) {
                minStop = stop;
            }
        }
        return minStop + 3;
    }

    public void printAll(String dna) {
        String localDna = dna.toUpperCase();
        int index = 0;
        while(index != -1 && index + 3 < localDna.length()) {
            index = localDna.indexOf(GENE_PREFIX, index);
            if(index == -1) {
                break;
            }
            int stop = findStopIndex(localDna, index + 3);
            if(stop < dna.length()) {
                System.out.println("From " + (index) + " to " + stop
                        + " Gene: " + dna.substring(index, stop));
            }
            index = stop;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FindMultiGenes4 FMG = new FindMultiGenes4();

        String[] dnaSamples = {"CATGTAATAGATGAATGACTGATAGATATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGACCCA",
                "catgtaatagatgaatgactgatagatatgcttgtatgctatgaaaatgtgaaatgaccca",
                "cAtGtAaTaGaTgAaTgAcTgAtAgAtAtGcTtGtAtGcTaTgAaAaTgTgAaAtGaCcCa",
                "ATGAAATGAAAA",
                "ccatgccctaataaatgtctgtaatgtaga"};

        for(String dna : dnaSamples) {
            System.out.println("DNA: " + dna);
            FMG.printAll(dna);
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
DNA: CATGTAATAGATGAATGACTGATAGATATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGACCCA
From 1 to 7 Gene: ATGTAA
From 10 to 22 Gene: ATGAATGACTGA
From 27 to 57 Gene: ATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGA

DNA: catgtaatagatgaatgactgatagatatgcttgtatgctatgaaaatgtgaaatgaccca
From 1 to 7 Gene: atgtaa
From 10 to 22 Gene: atgaatgactga
From 27 to 57 Gene: atgcttgtatgctatgaaaatgtgaaatga

DNA: cAtGtAaTaGaTgAaTgAcTgAtAgAtAtGcTtGtAtGcTaTgAaAaTgTgAaAtGaCcCa
From 1 to 7 Gene: AtGtAa
From 10 to 22 Gene: aTgAaTgAcTgA
From 27 to 57 Gene: AtGcTtGtAtGcTaTgAaAaTgTgAaAtGa

DNA: ATGAAATGAAAA
From 0 to 9 Gene: ATGAAATGA

DNA: ccatgccctaataaatgtctgtaatgtaga
From 2 to 11 Gene: atgccctaa
From 14 to 29 Gene: atgtctgtaatgtag
```

I have implemented the same algorithm using regular expression below, as it turns out, this is simpler than above.

**Using Regular Expression**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FindMultiGenes5 {
    /*(?i) : Case insensitive match
     * ATG : Starts with ATG
     * (\\w{3})*? : smallest string with length multiple of 3
     * (TGA|TAA|TAG) : one of TAG, TAA or TAG
     */
    private static final String GENE_REGEX = "(?i)ATG(\\w{3})*?(TGA|TAA|TAG)";

    public void regexMatch(String dna) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(GENE_REGEX).matcher(dna);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("From " + matcher.start() + " to " + matcher.end() + " Gene: " + matcher.group());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FindMultiGenes5 FMG = new FindMultiGenes5();

        String[] dnaSamples = {"CATGTAATAGATGAATGACTGATAGATATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGACCCA",
                "catgtaatagatgaatgactgatagatatgcttgtatgctatgaaaatgtgaaatgaccca",
                "cAtGtAaTaGaTgAaTgAcTgAtAgAtAtGcTtGtAtGcTaTgAaAaTgTgAaAtGaCcCa",
                "ATGAAATGAAAA",
                "ccatgccctaataaatgtctgtaatgtaga"};
        /*String[] dnaSamples = {"ATGaaabbbATGTGATAATGA".toLowerCase()};*/

        for(String dna : dnaSamples) {
            System.out.println("DNA: " + dna);
            FMG.regexMatch(dna);
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

**Regular Expression Output**

```
DNA: CATGTAATAGATGAATGACTGATAGATATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGACCCA
From 1 to 7 Gene: ATGTAA
From 10 to 22 Gene: ATGAATGACTGA
From 27 to 57 Gene: ATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGA

DNA: catgtaatagatgaatgactgatagatatgcttgtatgctatgaaaatgtgaaatgaccca
From 1 to 7 Gene: atgtaa
From 10 to 22 Gene: atgaatgactga
From 27 to 57 Gene: atgcttgtatgctatgaaaatgtgaaatga

DNA: cAtGtAaTaGaTgAaTgAcTgAtAgAtAtGcTtGtAtGcTaTgAaAaTgTgAaAtGaCcCa
From 1 to 7 Gene: AtGtAa
From 10 to 22 Gene: aTgAaTgAcTgA
From 27 to 57 Gene: AtGcTtGtAtGcTaTgAaAaTgTgAaAtGa

DNA: ATGAAATGAAAA
From 0 to 9 Gene: ATGAAATGA

DNA: ccatgccctaataaatgtctgtaatgtaga
From 2 to 11 Gene: atgccctaa
From 14 to 29 Gene: atgtctgtaatgtag
```

Comment: But what if I have a DNA string that's lowercase. What would I have to do to change this code?

Comment: The program has one flaw: it does not look past previous genes. Instead it finds overlapping genes. In the case with the dna strand ATGAAATGAAAA it finds no genes. Here are some example strands where the output genes are shown as well: DNA string is:

ATGAAATGAAAA

Gene found is:

ATGAAATGA 

DNA string is:

ccatgccctaataaatgtctgtaatgtaga

Genes found are:

atgccctaa

atgtctgtaatgtag

Comment: I didn't notice the correctness of the algorithm, modified the code in the answer to work correctly. Also I have tried the same thing using regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Alright,
You have / still have several problems. I can't really assist too much as I do not know the end goal. I don't know the rules around your algorithm.

I did however do a few things and ultimately it seems to work:
Firstly, sequence must be sent as a parameter and not dna, in line:

```
int stop = findStopIndex(dna, index);
```

becomes

```
int stop = findStopIndex(sequence, index);
```

You will then observe that your `newIndex` variable doesnt do much. The value always remain 0. Furthermore the check for -1 is therefore irrelevant. I changed the value in your output to `(stop + 3)`. Also note the parenthesis. Without it, it will be interpreted as string.

Other minor nice improvements include adding your values as variables instead of hardcoding them:

```
private final String[] STOP_SEQUENCES = {"tga", "taa", "tag"};
private final String START_SEQ = "atg";
```

And as a general rule, try avoid repeating code. In your `findStopIndex(String dna, int index)` code, you repeat a variable 3 times. This is nice and all until there are more variables. What is there were 50 000 stop codes?

The method could therefore be split up and made more general:

```
public int findStopIndex(String dna, int index) {
    int minStop = dna.length();
    int prevStop = dna.length();
    for (String stopSeq : STOP_SEQUENCES) {
        int stop = dna.indexOf(stopSeq, index);
        if (!hasStop(stop, index)) {
            stop = dna.length();
        }
        int tempMinStop = Math.min(stop, prevStop);
        minStop = minStop > tempMinStop ? tempMinStop : minStop;
        prevStop = stop;
    }
    return minStop;
}

public boolean hasStop(int stop, int index) {
    if (stop == -1 || (stop - index) % 3 != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And the `printAll(String dna)` method:

```
public void printAll(String dna) {
    String sequence = dna.toLowerCase();
    int index = 0;
    while (true) {
        index = sequence.indexOf(START_SEQ, index);
        if (index == -1) {
            break;
        }
        int stop = findStopIndex(sequence, index);
        if (stop != sequence.length()) {
            System.out.println("From " + (index) + " to " + (stop + 3) + " Gene: " + sequence.substring(index, stop + 3));
            index = stop;
        } else {
            index = index + 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note of the change made:

```
index = sequence.substring(index, stop + 3).length();
```

is now

```
index = stop;
```

to avoid an infinite loop.

---

This is all easily debuggable by built in debugging tools. A proper Java IDE should have a debugger.
for more information, please look up debugging with your IDE,
for instance, here is how to debug using Netbeans: [Netbeans Debugging](https://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/cdc-opt-impl/ojmeec/1.1/developer/html/debugging_netbeans.htm)

And here is one on Eclipse:
[Eclipse Debugging](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)

Beyond that, though this is a small program, printing out or logging values in certain areas of the program also helps a lot when it comes with solving unexpected output.

Comment: The end goal would be to have genes starting with ATG and ending with TAA, TGA, or TAG printed out if either one of the genes are a multiple of 3. If not multiple of 3 the program should skip to look for another codon ending with ie, TAG, etc. If there are multiple genes found, pick the smallest one and print that out. If no ATG start codon is found then terminate program. For more information on the algorithm see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459060/java-program-malfunction